# Locating an element with robot framework before the loading element timesout

Tags: reactjs, selenium, robotframework, business-logic

I'm trying to run a robot script and validate a page loading spinner in a React app but the spinner timesout before it can be validated/located. I've used both the xPath and CSS locator.

Is there an way to delay the timeout through robot framework?

Or allow it to identify the spinner before it timesout?

Comment: What do you mean by "times out" - the spinner disappears before selenium can get to it, as the data is loaded? If that, there's not a lot you can do - the system is just too fast in fetching and rendering the data. You could a) get it in a state where the data fetch is going to be slower (like - request very large dataset), or b) discuss with its developers to expose you a js method to delay the spinner hiding - but that's not recommended, you won't be testing the flow your users are exposed to.

Comment: Yes so the spinner disappears before selenium can locate it.

I was speaking to a friend of mine, he advised me that the business value of this test is worthless. The spinner is of no consequence whether it's there or not. The value is in the information that is displayed afterwards.

Thanks for the help.